# i want to implement camera and custom paint

Tags: flutter

Actually , i need a camera where after capturing a picture i can draw anything on that picture and save it.For that i already build a camera using camera plugin and custom paint . So now i want to merge this two. I am really confused about this matter. How can i do this ?

```
Here is my main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_better_camera/new/src/support_android/camera.dart';
import 'package:painter_demo/camera.dart';
import 'package:painter_demo/painting.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Camera App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Draw(),
      
    );
  }
}
```

Here i called the drawing class but i want to show over camera How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1):

First, put your camera view and custom paint(or image from your assets) in Stack, and there are 2 approaches for image generation:

1. Capture your picture with camera shot, merge camera image and your custom paint (or asset image) with this package, [image](https://pub.dev/packages/image), with this function:

   Image copyInto(Image dst, Image src, {int dstX, int dstY, int srcX, int srcY, int srcW, int srcH, bool blend = true});
   Copy an area of the src image into dst.
   Returns the modified dst image.
2. Make a custom button for screenshot (not camera shutter button), and follow the demo for screen shooting the Stack widget, [screenshot](https://codesearchonline.com/flutter-screenshot/)

Comment: Can you provide a sample code this it will be more helpful